# How to decrease the line spacing in LineSeparator itext

Tags: android, itext

I'm developing an Android application that build a custom PDF, I used itext as library support, but I have a big problem with the separator.

To separate the data I use this function:

```
public void addSeparator(PdfPCell cellToAdd){
    LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator();
    ls.setLineWidth(1);
    cellToAdd.addElement(new Chunk(ls));
}
```

cellToAdd is the cell where I need to add the LineSeparator, the idea of the result is:

```
my fantastic data

-----------------

Other data
```

I need to increase the space beetween the line and the data, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following screen shot:

[image]

The first cell shows the problem you describe. The second row solves it by changing a property of the `LineSeparator`. If that isn't sufficient, you need to change the `Paragraph` instances.

This is the code to create the full table:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.addCell(getCell1());
    table.addCell(getCell2());
    table.addCell(getCell3());
    table.addCell(getCell4());
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

The first cell is created like this:

```
public PdfPCell getCell1() {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("My fantastic data");
    cell.addElement(p1);
    LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator();
    cell.addElement(ls);
    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Other data");
    cell.addElement(p2);
    return cell;
}
```

We just add the `LineSeparator` and it sticks to the first paragraph. We can avoid this by introducing a negative offset:

```
public PdfPCell getCell2() {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("My fantastic data");
    cell.addElement(p1);
    LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator();
    ls.setOffset(-4);
    cell.addElement(ls);
    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Other data");
    cell.addElement(p2);
    return cell;
}
```

If more space is needed, we can increase the leading of the second paragraph and increase the offset:

```
public PdfPCell getCell3() {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("My fantastic data");
    cell.addElement(p1);
    LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator();
    ls.setOffset(-8);
    cell.addElement(ls);
    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Other data");
    p2.setLeading(25);
    cell.addElement(p2);
    return cell;
}
```

This may not be acceptable, because the leading will also have an effect on the subsequent lines if the *Other data* consists of more than one line.

The best solution is to use `setSpacingBefore()` or `setSpacingAfter()` (or both):

```
public PdfPCell getCell4() {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("My fantastic data");
    p1.setSpacingAfter(20);
    cell.addElement(p1);
    LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator();
    cell.addElement(ls);
    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Other data");
    p2.setSpacingBefore(10);
    cell.addElement(p2);
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## assuming you are using two columns#

```
cell = new PdfPCell();
// assuming you are using two column
cell.setColspan(2);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator();
// setting the color, this is for gray line
ls.setLineColor( new BaseColor(192, 192, 192, 120));
cell.addElement(ls);
table.addCell(cell);
```